tikz multipartite graph node arrangement
I am very new to tikz (and posting on stackexchange).
I am trying to draw a graph with 27 vertices, consisting of 9 independent sets of 3 vertices each.
All other edges are included.
With the code below, I get something like this:

Ideally, I would like for the 9 sets to be arranged in a 3x3 grid (so the vertices in each of the 9 sets form an empty triangle, and there are 9 of those triangles).
But I would be happy to just have the nodes spaced out more so that the edges are all visible.
Thank you!
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,final]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \graph [math nodes, nodes={circle, draw}] {
    {1, c, c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {a^2, a^2c, a^2c^2};
    {1, c, c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {a,ac,ac^2};
    {1, c, c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {ab,abc,abc^2};
    {1, c, c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {ab^2,ab^2c,ab^2c^2};
    {1, c, c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {b,bc,bc^2};
    {1, c, c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {a^2b^2,a^2b^2c,a^2b^2c^2};
    %
    {a^2, a^2c, a^2c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {a,ac,ac^2};
    {a^2, a^2c, a^2c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {ab,abc,abc^2};
    {a^2, a^2c, a^2c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {ab^2,ab^2c,ab^2c^2};
    {a^2, a^2c, a^2c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {b,bc,bc^2};
    {a^2, a^2c, a^2c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {a^2b^2,a^2b^2c,a^2b^2c^2};
    %
    {a,ac,ac^2} -- [complete bipartite] {ab,abc,abc^2};
    {a,ac,ac^2} -- [complete bipartite] {ab^2,ab^2c,ab^2c^2};
    {a,ac,ac^2} -- [complete bipartite] {b,bc,bc^2};
    {a,ac,ac^2} -- [complete bipartite] {a^2b^2,a^2b^2c,a^2b^2c^2};
    %
    {ab,abc,abc^2} -- [complete bipartite] {ab^2,ab^2c,ab^2c^2};
    {ab,abc,abc^2} -- [complete bipartite] {b,bc,bc^2};
    {ab,abc,abc^2} -- [complete bipartite] {a^2b^2,a^2b^2c,a^2b^2c^2};
    %
    {ab^2,ab^2c,ab^2c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {b,bc,bc^2};
    {ab^2,ab^2c,ab^2c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {a^2b^2,a^2b^2c,a^2b^2c^2};
    %
    {a^2b^2,a^2b^2c,a^2b^2c^2} -- [complete bipartite] {b,bc,bc^2};
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE!
